# Does .NET 7.0 have a method to OR a list of flag enums?

Tags: .net

Does .NET 7.0 already have an in-built way to what `OrFlags` does below?

```
[Flags]
enum Props
{
    Good, Male, Big
}
record Dog(string Name, Props Prop);
static Props OrFlags(IEnumerable<Props> list)
{
    Props res = list.First();
    foreach (Props p in list)
    {
        res |= p;
    }

    return res;
}

public static async Task Main()
{
    var list = new List<Dog>();
    list.Add(new Dog("Max", Props.Male));
    list.Add(new Dog("Max", Props.Big));
    list.Add(new Dog("Jane", Props.Good));

    var res = from d in list
                        group d.Prop by d.Name into g
                        select new {Name= g.Key, Properties = OrFlags(g)};

    foreach(var d in res)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(d.Name +": " + d.Properties);
    }
```

Output

```
Max: Male, Big
Jane: Good
```